# SSIS Export data from Excel to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm running a package on SSIS, I run the package on Visual Studio 2015 (data tools), I get all green light, everything seems to be fine but I get no result on the table (destination table), I'm trying to delete all the record from destination table before import data from an Excel Workbook. Even transformation doesn't work out, they work out (sort of) on Visual Studio, but they don't affect the destination.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I notice that if I import data from a flat file into a SQL Server table, using SSIS (Visual Studio Data tools) and Set a Delete from... SQL Script, every time that I run the package over and over again the data from the table is deleted...but when I try to import data from an Excel worksheet I can transfer the data but it seems that SQL Statements doesn´t work out.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say what's going on with no data samples and no screen shots, but it should definitely work.  I do the same thing you are doing, all day long, in my office, using Excel, SSIS, and SQL Server.  Can you try using Excel VBA to load the data into SQL Server?

```
Sub UpdateTable()

    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Excel_to_SQL_Server.xls"
    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=[Northwind].[dbo].[TBL]]"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"
    cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    wbkOpen.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing

End Sub

Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Excel-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the connection
cnn.Open
'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET JOIN_DT = 2013-01-13 WHERE EMPID = 2"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, consider the option below to move data from Excel to SQL Server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml;
   Database=C:\DataFiles\EmployeeData1.xlsx',
   [vEmployee$]); 


SELECT * 
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Data Source=C:\DataFiles\EmployeeData1.xlsx;
   Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml')...[vEmployee$];
```

Also, if you have headers...

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;
   Database=C:\DataFiles\EmployeeData1.xlsx',
   [vEmployee$]);
```

Likewise, no headers...

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=NO;
   Database=C:\DataFiles\EmployeeData1.xlsx',
   [vEmployee$]);
```

Etc., etc., etc.